# powershell script to check KBs specific to server

Tags: powershell

I writing below script to verify certain set of KBs present or not in Windows Servers. 
Each Windows version has recommended KBs should be installed. This code is working fine. But i want to add a new noteproperty  to $object as "Comments" and its Value should a custom message like "Problem" or "Good" based on some conditions.

**Conditions:**

- if all  $kb is Missing  --> Problem
- if all $kb is Installed--> Good
- if highest $kb is Installed --> Good

**Actual Conditions**

- Windows Server 2008, SP1, SP2, R2 and R2 SP1 require KB2754704 installed to resolve issue with MPIO path failover
- Windows Server 2008 R2 and R2 SP1 requires KB2821052 installed to resolve issue with MPIO path failover
- Windows Server 2008 SP2 requires KB2878031 installed to resolve an issue with MPIO path failover
- Windows Server 2012 and 2012 R2 requires KB3046101 installed to resolve issue with MPIO path failover

**Code**

```
$Hotfixes = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_QuickFixEngineering
$OSName = Get-WmiObject win32_operatingsystem | select Caption -expa Caption
$Kbs = $null
if($OSName -match "2008 R2")
{
    $Kbs = @('KB2754704','KB2821052','KB2869606')
}
if($OSName -match "2008 SP2")
{
    $Kbs = @('KB2878031')
}
if($OSName -match "2012 R2")
{
    $kbs = @('KB3046101','KB3121261')
}
if($OSName -match "2012")
{
    $kbs = @('KB3046101')
}
$ht = [ordered]@{} 
foreach($kb in $Kbs) 
{ 
  $st =  $Hotfixes.HotFixID -contains $kb
  $ht[$kb] = $st 
}
$object = new-object psobject
$object | add-member  -MemberType noteproperty -name Server -Value $env:COMPUTERNAME
$object | add-member  -MemberType noteproperty -name OSName -Value $OSName
$object | add-member  -MemberType noteproperty -name Comments -Value ""
$object
```

What changes i should make here to fulfill those 3 conditions to pass ? irrespective of Kb count in $Kbs array.
I created a hashtable for $Kbs with all $true to compare with other hashtable

```
$ht
Name                           Value                                              
----                           -----                                              
KB2754704                      False                                              
KB2821052                      False                                              
KB2869606                      True   

$DHash = [ordered]@{} 
$Kbs | ForEach-Object {$DHash.Add($_,$true)}

$DHash
Name                           Value                                              
----                           -----                                            
KB2754704                      True                                               
KB2821052                      True                                               
KB2869606                      True
```

Here i am struck to proceed further to write condition. I used compare-object but it results side indicator.  I am not actually sure how to achieve this functionality. So posting my query here to get some ideas / help.

Answer (score 0):

You could make `$ht` the type of `PSCustomObject` and select the last element (which is the "highest" KB). If that is `$true`, you are good. If not, you have a problem, because none, or not the latest patch is installed

```
$ht = foreach ($kb in $Kbs) 
{ 
    $st = $Hotfixes.HotFixID -contains $kb
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        kb = $kb
        st = $st
    }
}

$ht = $ht | Sort-Object -Property kb

if ($ht[-1] -eq $true) {
    $Comment = 'Good'
}
else {
    $Comment = 'Problem'
}
```